# Send Command To Function

Tags: java, android, function

how can i send a command to a function , for example .

```
{
    {
    boolean b;

    Do(b, b = false);
    }

    public void Do (boolean b,Command command)
    {
        if (b == true)
        {
            command;
        }
    }

}
```

so if b = true it should turn it to false in this example .
any ideas ? 
i am using android studio - java
Thanks

Comment: The second parameter needs to be an instance of ``Command``, so your ``Do(b, b = false);`` does not compile. No idea which ``Command`` you use, but it needs a method such as ``execute``, ``call`` etc. which you need to use to execute that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define the structure of your command. You need to define the exact # and types of each argument your 'command' is to take, what an invocation of 'command' returns (which type), and which checked exceptions it is allowed to throw, if any.

Once you've decided on that, either find an appropriate existing functional interface, or make one yourself.

What is a functional interface? Simply an interface that has exactly 1 (non-default) method in it. For example, there is `java.lang.Runnable` defined like so:

```
public interface Runnable {
    void run();
}
```

which means: This command takes no arguments, returns nothing, and cannot throw any checked exceptions.

Once you've done all that you can create them fairly easily. This acts like an object, so you can just call `.run()` on the result:

```
public void test() {
    Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello!");
    doTwice(r);
    // you can one-liner it too of course:
    doTwice(() -> System.out.println("World!"));
}

public void doTwice(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
    r.run();
}
```

The above will print 'Hello!' twice and then 'World!' twice.

**However**, in your pseudocode you are trying to change a value of a local variable inside the code you 'send' to the other method. This is not allowed in java; any local variables used in one of these code blocks needs to be effectively final, which means: They are initialized exactly once and never changed again.

A way out of the dilemma is to make that an `AtomicBoolean` which is a mutable object. Then you'd get something like:

```
AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);
runTwice(()-> b.set(true));
System.out.println(b); // Prints true
```

You've asked about android; the above features were introduced in java 8. While java 8 is almost 5 years old by now, android is more or less a fork of java and it was forked before java 8 was introduced. I don't know if android supports these constructs. Google or ask around if android supports 'lambdas' (which is what the above stuff does).

If android does *not* support lambdas, it's still possible but real, real ugly:

```
runTwice(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked , i dont know if u were the one who posted the first answer with then deleted it , but it worked the first time and yes it does support lambdas , it asked me to change the language to level 8 - lambdas ( i think it was that way) and once i did that it worked .

Comment: IMPORTANT : you should add    android { compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    } }    in your build.gradle(module app)